# Add the Latest rows into a table from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

Hope you can help.

In `[DB1].[TableA]` I have a list of data all with unique ID's. 
The same data is in `[DB2].[TableB]` but is always updated and new data is inserted here.

I want to be able to insert any new data from `[DB2].[TableB]` into `[DB1].[TableA]`.

I may want it to run as a SQL job on a schedule to check if there are any news and then insert them into `TableA` from `TableB`. Maybe 3 times a day.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Will you have updates or deletes on [DB2].[TableB]? Or just INSERTS And I assume you mean DB2.dbo.tableB. SQL Server uses schema. And SQL Server 2008+ or earlier (there are new features that make it easier)

Comment: DB2 is situated on a linked server and i want to take all the new data from that and insert it into may own daily. A Bulk insert wouldnt work because of he amount.

Comment: Sorry pressed enter so unfinished. Ive tried using it to get all the record with todays date and insert them but i cant access the data types so theres always an error. I think the server is 2008 R2

Comment: I asked about 1. deletes 2. update 3. version. I never asked about bulk insert.

Comment: Latest rows is not the same as "today's date". Do you want more or different rows in tableA if data changes on TableB? Find out versions with SELECT @@VERSION

Comment: Sorry, i just need to insert the latest data from TableB into TableA. Can this be done by checking for new ID's that arent present in TableA and then inserting that information? The version is 2005 x64

Comment: yes, this is easiest. As per Daryl Wenman-Bateson's answer

Comment: Can i not have multiple field names in the Insert into part. Because i am only selecting part of the other table to insert into a few field in the destination table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple approach would be to create a scheduled job with an update script like;

```
INSERT INTO TestDB.DB1.TableA (id, firstname)
SELECT  tfr.Id, tfr.firstname
FROM    TestDB.DB2.TableB tfr
LEFT JOIN   TestDB.DB1.TableA tto on tfr.Id = tto.tid
WHERE   tto.id is null
```

Set the tasks schedule to repeat daily and either set the frequency to every x hours or set three schedules at specific times.

If you need something more complex to manage TableB data changes and logging, maybe consider creating an SSIS package to encompass your data flow logic.

Comment: Thanks alot,sorry im just starting out at this so excuse me for asking naive questions but what does tfr, tto mean in the code?

Comment: Got it, Table from and Table to?! I'll try it and let you know. thanks agin

Comment: Can i not have multiple field names in the Insert into part. Because i am only selecting part of the other table to insert into a few field in the destination table.

Comment: Have amended example to accommodate  inserting into specific fields